# Stored Procedure in datediff

Tags: sql-server

Couldn't execute stored proc. in date diff

```
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2012-11-23',(exec AddValorDate 3,'2012-11-26'))
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will solve your problem if you cannot convert the stored procedure to a function.

declare @date table
(
    theDate datetime
)

insert into @date
exec AddValorDate 3,'2012-11-26'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2012-11-23',theDate) from @date

Answer (score 0):

You should make AddValorDate a function rather than a stored procedure. Then you can call it in your query.